# VS2015 - Creating a Class Diagram and Generating Code in C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to generate code from a UML ClassDiagram complied in C++?
Whenever I chose to generate code it will always generate a project in C#

New Project -> Modeling Projects -> New Item -> UML Class Diagram -> Generate Code